# Failed to load webpage with error: Frame load interrupted

Tags: cordova

I see this has been asked before but I dont see any solutions:

So Im using Cordova 2.5 to build an iPad app on iOS 6.1.2

My app.coffee:

```
jQuery ->
    class window.AppRouter extends Backbone.Router
        routes: {
            '': 'index',
            ':parent/:child/': 'childView',
            ':id/': 'detailView',
        },

        index: =>
            $("#navbar .title").text("Flight Centre's Choices")
            view = new fc.main.View
            view.render()

        childView: (parent, child) =>
            view = new fc.main.View(parent:parent, child:child)
            view.render()

        detailView: (id) =>
            view = new fc.main.Detail(id:id)
            view.render()

    window.app = new AppRouter();
    Backbone.history.start();
```

The first index view loads successfully and displays as it should

Now clicking on one of the links to lets say open childView, it fails to load the page:

```
2013-03-20 16:56:13.684 Flight[1158:907] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2013-03-20 16:56:13.689 Flight[1158:907] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2013-03-20 16:56:13.694 Flight[1158:907] Failed to load webpage with error: Frame load interrupted
```

the link the user clicks on looks like this':

```
/#/foo/bar/
```

Everything works as expected in Chrome browser on my mac.

I dont know whats happening here!!

Answer (score 35):

Damn this waisted allot of time, the answer was so dumb and simple.

Rather than having the links in the html as :

```
/#/foo/bar/
```

It should just be

```
#/foo/bar/
```

this makes sense, with the leading / the page will reload, and thats why I got that error.

Hope it helps someone

Comment: Yep, had the same problem with Phonegap 3 and AngularJS... thank God for Google!

Comment: For those that may come later, this did *not* solve my problem when linking via ng-href. Invoking $location.path('/route_name') via a method call in ng-click did work, however... Curiouser and curiouser...

Comment: In my case, I was already using #/ in all the links. Even though I tried both #/ and /#/ the only thing that worked was leaving the links as they were and removing <base href="/">

Answer (score 0):

I could solve it by using window.location.hash