# Phonegap: Failed to load webpage with error: The request timed out

Tags: cordova

I've built iPhone app with phone gap. When I run the app sometimes I get the following error:

2014-02-07 00:17:37.168 [1867:60b] Unlimited access to network resources
2014-02-07 00:17:42.459 [1867:60b] Resetting plugins due to page load.
2014-02-07 00:18:03.887 [1867:60b] Failed to load webpage with error: The request timed out.

And sometimes it works Ok.

Thanks.

Comment: are you linking to any external files like JS or images?

Comment: Nope. And what's strange is that sometimes it works.

Comment: I've seen this issue, but it's typically when loading external resources fails. Do you have any JS that maybe failing before the DOM is fully loaded?

Comment: I've just double checked - no external resources. The app even works sometimes without any internet connection.

Comment: Yeah, just wondering if you have any javascript code in the project that may be failing (internal code). Basically if the page can't fully render you will get the error you are getting.

Comment: Same issue for me… do you use plugins?

Comment: Check this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15527120/